# Getting Mongoid to render csv text

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoid

Is there a fast/efficient way to get mongodb or mongoid to return csv text, without piping it into ruby etc first?

I'm going for something performant here that could returnt he csv text straight from the database.  Thank you!

Comment: MongoDB definitely does not as part of the API (which is what I presume you mean). I can't imagine mongoid having anything either as CSV and a object-based system aren't the best matches, structurally speaking. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mongoexport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) has a whole slew of options to just do that. It is shipped with the binaries.

```
mongoexport --db <the database you want to export> --csv
```

You can select a collection to export. However, that is as much control you'd get this way. If you wanted a single document or the result of a single query, you can't do it using `mongoexport`